# Str_replace in Blade file if any of the words match

Tags: php, laravel, string, laravel-blade, str-replace

I have a critical case; I want to replace words if any given string matches a specific string inside my Laravel Blade file.

```
@php
    $stringToReplace = 'Very Good Developer';
    $stringFrom = 'You are a Good Developer';

    echo str_replace($stringToReplace, '', $stringFrom);
@endphp
```

If for other cases...

```
$strinToReplace = 'Good sensed Developer Man';
```

I want to replace at least the matched words **any matched word** matching in `$stringFrom` with `$stringToReplace`, it should replace.

Comment: What does `@php` mean? PHP code starts with `<?php`.

Comment: @Barmar Actually she seems to be using Laravel framework where we have those `@php` tags inside a view blade file. She should have mentioned it though. When blade compiles, it anyways gets converted from `@php` to `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of string use array to replace any of the word

```
$stringToReplace = array('Very', 'Good', 'Developer');
$stringFrom = 'You are a Good Developer';

echo str_replace($stringToReplace, '',$stringFrom);
```

for dynamic you can use like this

```
$stringToReplace = 'Very Good Developer';
$stringToReplace = explode(' ',$stringToReplace);
$stringFrom = 'You are a Good Developer';

echo str_replace($stringToReplace, '',$stringFrom);
```

Comment: What if $stringToReplace is dynamic, pleasee see the question again

Comment: @RiyaSingh  for dynamic you can use explode to convert in array, I am updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You may use the explode function together with the str_replace function to do the job:

```
<?php
///////////////////////////
function specialreplacenew($source, $replacestring) {
$pieces = explode(" ", $replacestring);
$count=count($pieces);

$index=0;

$newstring=$source;

while ($index <$count) {

$newstring=str_replace($pieces[$index], '', $newstring);
$index++; }
return $newstring;
}
///////////////////////////



$stringToReplace = 'Good sensed Developer Man';
$stringFrom = 'You are a Good Developer';

echo specialreplacenew($stringFrom, $stringToReplace);

?>
```

Link to show the effect:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db6cbac8996281c39bf19caaf3b2042ba88d075d

Comment: Error: Cannot redeclare specialreplace()

Comment: I am using Laravel, maybe some issue

Comment: Oh if I remember correctly Laravel has **specialReplace** function (that's why it crashes in your case). So I have revised my answer to use another function name. -- please try my revised answer again.

Comment: It works, But I wanted something else. Please see the updated question.

Comment: check by **$stringToReplace = 'Good Man Developer Sense';** it will throw $source

Comment: problem fixed. Try again if you wish

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression so that `Very` will be optional when matching.

```
$regexp = '/(Very )?Good Developer/';
$stringFrom = 'You are a Good Developer';
echo preg_replace($regexp, '', $stringFrom);
```

Comment: What if in other case, I have not the word 'very' but some other word?

Comment: You can use alternatives: `(Very |Pretty |Somewhat )?`

Comment: But my $stringToReplace is dynamic which can be anything from database of three words, four or any

Comment: How do you know which words are required and which are optional?

Comment: I just call the words using a$strinToReplace and I want if any of the words matched, it should replace, if it does not match any of the word so nothing

Comment: In the question you said you want to replace at least `Good Developer`. So not `Good` or `Developer` by themselves, it has to be both words, right? But `Very` doesn't have to be in the string. So there's something different between them, how do you get that from the DB?

Comment: Updated the question